# childNode.remove() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script

I'm writing a google sheets add on that helps you track data as you play a game. In the sidebar, you can search for a monster in the game and after you hit the submit button the monster's stats, a list of what items they drop after a kill, and a link to the wiki is rendered on screen.

The problem I'm having is that when you search a new monster after having already searched for one, the old items from the drop section won't get removed. The other sections on stats and the wiki link will change, but instead of removing the old drop items, the new items just get added to the end of the list.

I've tried using `parent.removeChild()` and `childNode.remove()` and neither seem to do anything and I'm wondering if its because of how google apps script works.

Here is the html for the sidebar itself: note that `include()` is a custom function that google recommends you add to your script so you can import other files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Info sidebar styles'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="monsters">
      <input class="monsterInput" type="text"placeholder="Monster Name" name="monsterName" />
      <input class="monsterInput" type="text" placeholder="Monster Level" name="monsterLvl" />
      <button id="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
  <?!= include('sidebar script'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for sidebar script:

```
<script>
    if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
    } else {
    ready()
    }
    function ready(){
    // create the divs that are later filled with info
      var output = document.getElementById("output");
      var stats = document.createElement("div");
      stats.id = "statsDiv";
      var drops = document.createElement("div");
      drops.id = 'dropDiv';
      var list = document.createElement("div");
      list.id = "dropList";
      var wiki = document.createElement("div");
      wiki.id = "wiki";
      output.appendChild(stats);
      output.appendChild(drops);
      output.appendChild(wiki);
      var index = 0;
   // the onSuccess for the onClick eventHandler. data is an object returned from the function call below  
      function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(`first index ${index}`);
   // if the submit button has already been pushed and added the droplist to the DOM, increase the index
        if(drops.getElementsByClassName("dropItem")[0]){
          index++;
          console.log(`second index ${index}`);
        };
        console.log(index);
    // get the stats
        var hitpoints = data.hitpoints;
        var attackarray = data["attack_type"]
        var attackTypes = '';
        var attack1 = attackarray[0];
        var attack2 = attackarray[1];
        var attack3 = attackarray[2];
        var attack4 = attackarray[3];
        if(attackarray.length === 1){
            attackTypes = attack1;
        } else if (attackarray.length === 2){
            attackTypes = `${attack1}, ${attack2}`;
        } else if (attackarray.length === 3){
            attackTypes = `${attack1}, ${attack2}, ${attack3}`;
        } else if (attackarray.length === 4){
            attackTypes = `${attack1}, ${attack2}, ${attack2}, ${attack4}`;
        }
        var attLvl = data["attack_level"];
        var defLvl = data["defence_level"];
        var magicLvl = data["magic_level"];
        var rangeLvl = data["ranged_level"];
        var maxHit = data["max_hit"];
        var aggro = '';
        if(data.aggressive){
          aggro = "Yes";
        } else {
          aggro = "No";
        }
        var speed = data["attack_speed"];
          // put the stats into html form
        var statsInner = 
          `<h2> Stats </h2>
           <ul id="statsList">
             <li>Hitpoints: ${hitpoints}</li>
             <li>Attack Level: ${attLvl}</li>
             <li>Defense Level: ${defLvl}</li>
             <li>Magic Level: ${magicLvl}</li>
             <li>Ranged Level: ${rangeLvl}</li>
             <li>Attack Style: ${attackTypes} </li>
             <li>Attack Speed: ${speed}</li>
             <li>Max Hit: ${maxHit} </li>
             <li>Aggressive? ${aggro} </li>
           </ul>`;
         stats.innerHTML = statsInner;
         drops.innerHTML = '<h2>Drops</h2>';
          // Put the wiki url into HTML
         var wikiURL = data["wiki_url"];
         var wikiInner = `<p>For more info check out this monsters page on the wiki, <a href=${wikiURL}>here</a>.</p>`;
         wiki.innerHTML = wikiInner;
         // get the drop information and put it in html form. make the data-id attribute of each object equal the value of index
         data.drops.forEach(function (item) {
           var name = item.name;
           var quant = item.quantity;
           var members = '';
           if(item.members){
             members = "(m)";
            }
            var nameQM = `${name} (x${quant}) ${members}`;
            var rarity = (item.rarity) * 100;
            var rare = rarity.toFixed(2);
            var nameNode = document.createElement("div");
            var itemList = 
            `<p>${nameQM}</p>
             <br>
             <p> Rarity: ${rare} percent </p>`;
            nameNode.innerHTML = itemList;
            nameNode.className = "dropItem";
            nameNode.dataset.id = index;
            list.appendChild(nameNode);
          })
        drops.appendChild(list);
     // if the drop item has a data-id that doesn't match the current index, remove it from the DOM.
        var dropArray = list.getElementsByClassName("dropItem");
        for(var i = 0; i < dropArray.length; i++){
          var item = dropArray[i];
          if(item.dataset.id != index){
           item.remove();
          }
        }
      }
      //add the event listener to the submit button. getMonsterData makes an API call, parses the data, and returns an object filled with the data we add to the DOM through the success handler
      document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var monsterName = parent.elements[0].value;
        var monsterlvl = parent.elements[1].value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getMonsterData(monsterName, monsterlvl);
      });
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: There are no such restrictions that I know of.

Comment: You can build the html server side and then just load it into a container client side.

Comment: To answer your title, No. You need to debug your actual problem. Start by looking into dev console.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then. Within the for loop where the items should be removed, I added a log statement and it logs when i expect it to:
```
var dropArray = list.getElementsByClassName("dropItem");
        for(var i = 0; i < dropArray.length; i++){
          var item = dropArray[i];
          if(item.dataset.id != index){
           item.remove();
 console.log(“x”);
          }

```
Everything executes how i expect it except for the child.remove() call